# Norm of a difference of two elements in Quadratic Fields

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, normed-spaces

everyone. Hope you can help me out.

I ran across this question and have absolutely no idea how to go about:

"Let $X =x+y\sqrt{2}$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Show that there is an element $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ such that $|N(X-Q)|<1$. Hence show that ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is norm-Euclidean"

$N$ here represents the norm which is defined as :$N(A)=A\overline{A}$ where $\overline{A}$ is a conjugate of $A$.

What the question is asking seems quite logical, but I cant figure out the way to prove it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are basically being asked:

Given

$$X = x + y \sqrt{2} $$

Can you find $a_1, b_1$ such that

$$ |(x - a_1) + (y - b_1) \sqrt{2}| < 1 $$

If so then:

$$ Q = a_1 + b_1 \sqrt{2}$$

Is the value that you are seeking.

Note here that if

$$ a_1 = x - 1$$

Then $$x - a_1 = 1$$

Furthermore if

$$ b_1 = y_1 + 1$$

Then

$$ y_1 - b_1 = -1$$

And thus:

$$|(x - a_1) + (y - b_1) \sqrt{2}| = |1 - \sqrt{2}| < 1$$

So:

$$Q = (x_1 - 1) + (y_1 + 1) \sqrt{2}$$

Is such an element

Comment: but how does one go about using this knowledge to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is norm-Eculidian

Comment: It seems I haven't answered you're question actually, I missed the N componenet.